# use indexnumber in for loop python

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, indexing, counter

So I have this code

```
fieldnames = (
        'Woonplaats', 'Kleur', 'Naam', 'Merk', 'Deuraantal', 'Leeftijd', 'Vloeistof', 'Snelheid', 'Tankstation',
        'Ramen')     

for line in range(100000):
    writer.writerow({fieldnames[0]: tup[0][random.randrange(10)],
                     fieldnames[1]: tup[1][random.randrange(10)],
                     fieldnames[2]: tup[2][random.randrange(10)],
                     fieldnames[3]: tup[3][random.randrange(10)],
                     fieldnames[4]: tup[4][random.randrange(10)],
                     fieldnames[5]: tup[5][random.randrange(10)],
                     fieldnames[6]: tup[6][random.randrange(10)],
                     fieldnames[7]: tup[7][random.randrange(10)],
                     fieldnames[8]: tup[8][random.randrange(10)],
                     fieldnames[9]: tup[9][random.randrange(10)]})
```

I have different tuples inside a tuple which I am refering to with the `tup[0],tup[1]`. The goal is to create a csv file with randomly chosen values from the tuples. Here's a sample of my csv file

```
Nijmegen,wit,Henk,Citroen,5,70,whiskey,90,Q8,7
Eindhoven,groen,Klaas,Volkswagen,3,50,limonade,70,Total,5
Utrecht,geel,Piet,Ford,2,40,water,60,Esso,4
Nijmegen,wit,Henk,Citroen,5,70,whiskey,90,Q8,7
```

Now I wonder if there's a way to automatically fill in the numbers `0` to `9`, because I imagine if the columns get larger, you can't type this out. I tried this with a for loop, but I just got a bunch of commas and some values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for line in range(100000):
    writer.writerow({fieldnames[i] : tup[i][random.randrange(10)] for i in range(10)})
```

Comment: I get an syntax error with this, there's no closing square bracket. I think you meant writer.writerow({fieldnames[i] : tup[i][random.randrange](10) for i in range(10)}). That does work, thanks!

Comment: Oops, edited my answer to include the `]`. Please accept if it works, thanks!